# How to call OSB Proxy from Java and C#

Tags: c#, java, proxy, client-server, osb

I need examples for both situation: how invoke OSB Proxy from Java Client and how invoke from C# Client. I am looking for simple examples and advanced best practices as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on the type of proxy that you have created and the protocol that it is using. What is the transport type of the proxy?

If your proxy service is WSDL based and accepts SOAP/HTTP, then you may call the service like you will make any WebService call.

P.S.: You already asked this question here on [OTN](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10682962).